# Random errors from watson speech-to-text using websockets

Tags: python, websocket, ibm-watson

I am using IBM watson's speech-to-text API using websockets. Sometimes it works just fine, but other times I get random errors such as:

- [WinError 10014] The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call
- [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:1977)
- Session timed out.

Regarding the last error, it is important to note that I am not defining any timeout and even when I do define a large enough timeout it still happends.

Moreover, sometimes my on_close() callback function is suddenly being invoked.

I'm using Python 3.5.2 64-bit on a windows machine. ibm_watson version is 2.10.0 but this happend also on watson-developer-cloud 2.5.0.

The code I'm using is quite straightforward from the examples given.

```
self.speech_to_text.recognize_using_websocket(audio=self.audio_source,
                                                     content_type='audio/l16; rate=44100',
                                                     recognize_callback=self.mycallback,
                                                     interim_results=True,
                                                     timestamps=True,
                                                     profanity_filter=False,
                                                     smart_formatting=True
                                                     )
```

Comment: Can you share the things you are seeing? The what happens before and after the error messages is important. **`on_close()`** can be invoked also when the other side terminates the websocket.

Comment: [LOG] Error received: [WinError 10014] The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call. 
[LOG] Connection closed. 
--- or --- 

[LOG] Error received: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:1977). 
[LOG] Connection closed.